# AND/NAND LED Flasher circuit help?

Tags: timer, nand

I've come across a circuit I'm not too familiar with:

[image]
([Goggle Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bws5pmYyaBJSSFdqaVRUcldoOXc/view?usp=sharing) version)

How do I tune R1, R2, R3, and C1 to adjust frequency and duty cycle?

I get the general idea of how it works, but I've asked 4 engineers that I work with already, and the only answer I get is "That's an old school approach, ask the other guy". I'd like a better understanding of how this circuit works - Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remember this circuit will only work if your first NAND gate has Schmitt trigger inputs.

Comment: @Doodle it does not have them but the circuit works. Just not sure how to tune it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how your circuit works without schmitt trigger inputs. Your output should be flickering all over the place using something like a 74HC00. Transistors answer tells you how to tune it exactly.

Comment: That's two of us. Which is why I posted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initial conditions:

- C1 discharged so NAND pin 4 is high.
- This feeds back to AND pin 1 and since 2 is permanently high AND pin 4 goes high charging up C via the parallel paths of (R1 and diode) and R3.
- When C1 voltage is high enough NAND pin 4 goes low.
- AND pin 1 now goes low and C discharges through R3 only.
- Repeat.

The diode makes the waveform asymmetric. C charges through R1 and R3 but can only discharge through R3.

> How do I tune R1, R2, R3, and C1 to adjust frequency and duty cycle?

- C1 charge-up time, \$ \tau_1 \$, will be given approximately by the time constant \$(R1 || R3) \times C\$. (where "||" is the parallel resistor value.)
- The discharge time, \$ \tau_2 \$, by \$R3 \times C\$.
- The total period of each cycle will be \$ {\tau_1 + \tau_2} \$.
- The frequency will be \$ \frac {1}{\tau_1 + \tau_2} \$.
- The duty cycle will be \$ \frac {\tau_1}{\tau_1 + \tau_2} \$.
- The diode introduces a further slight complication in that there is a voltage drop across it. The effect seems to have been minimised by using a Schottky diode which has a lower voltage drop than a regular silicon diode.

---

> The \$V_{IH} \$ level is 3.5 V, and the \$V_{OL} \$ level is 1.6 V. How does that change the equation?

It doesn't. I assumed the thresholds would be about those proportions.

Going from low to high C will initially be at 1.6 V and the charging voltage close to 5 V. Switching will take place at 3.5 V which is \$ \frac {3.5 - 1.6}{5 - 1.6} = 56\% \$ of the way to fully charged. You can see from Figure 1 that this is quite close to the 63% value of one RC time constant, \$ \tau \$.

Going from high to low C will initially be at 3.5 V and the discharging voltage close to 0 V. Switching will take place at 1.6 V which is \$ \frac {3.5 - 1.6}{3.5} = 55\% \$ of the way to fully discharged. This time you can see from Figure 1 that this is not close to one time constant, \$ \tau \$ but probably good enough.

Don't forgot that you will have variation from chip to chip.

[image]

*Figure 1. RC charge / discharge curve.*

> Furthermore, what role does R2 play? I was presuming there was some discharge through it, at one point at least....

On power-off the NAND gate will have no supply. C will discharge through the input protection diodes and will try to power up everything on the PCB that's connected to that power rail. R2 limits that current to a value that the protection diodes can handle. In normal operation it has no effect on the timing because the NAND inputs have such high impedence - typically GΩ.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, Andrew. Too much of a hurry, I'm afraid.

Comment: I recommend you wait a day or so before accepting the answer. You might get a better one.

Comment: if I only had the time... lol

Comment: Besides, it's locked. I can't uncheck it if I wanted to. Let's see what pops up.

Comment: let me throw a cog in the works - these are 5V parts, and the VIH level is 3.5V, and the VOL level is 1.6V. How does that change the equation? Or do I need the exponential function for this?

Comment: furthermore, what role does R2 play? I was presuming there was some discharge through it, at one point at least....

Comment: See the updates.

Comment: Ok, so something doesn't seem to add up. I tried it with R1= 100k, R2= 10k, R3 = 470k, and C1=22uF. By these calcs I should have a 1.8s charge, a 10.3s discharge. I got an 8Hz flash instead... could it be because the NAND doesn't have a Schmitt input? this is the NAND I'm using in my test: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/nc7wz00-305128.pdf

Comment: Your calculations are correct. Your measurements indicate something is out by a factor of 100. Check your component values - particularly C. Note that the low-level input voltage max is guaranteed to be read as a 'low'. Voltages somewhat above that may also be read as low. Same with the high level min. You are working in an undefined area of operation.

Comment: Ok, well, I'm going to calculate something up and try it. I'll report back and let you (all) know.

Comment: So I have a no-schmitt NAND, I'm going to order one with a ST Input and try again tomorrow. I'll update you then.

Comment: While you're waiting you could try adding a bit of hysteresis to the NAND by connecting a 100k between 4 and 1. That may make it a bit more Schmitt trigger-ish.

Comment: I put in the Schmitt NAND. Now the circuit behaves more like the math.  Thank you.  The off time is not correct, but we're working it out...